# Coupon Collector. How do I improve my code to get better runtime?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, optimization

This is a coupon collector code to analyze the running time. I need some suggestions on how to improve the running times of this code? I have used the data structure dictionary but is there any other data structure that will perform faster.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from array import *
import timeit

trailList = {}

def couponcollector(n):
    numDic = {}
    trails = 0
    while len(numDic) < n:
        num = np.random.random_integers(n);
        trails = trails + 1
        if num not in numDic.keys():
            numDic[num] = 1

    return trails


def starter(n,m):
    summ = 0
    for i in range(0,m):
        r = couponcollector(n)
        summ = summ + r
        if trailList.has_key(r):
            trailList[r] = trailList[r] + 1
        else:
            trailList[r] = 1
    print trailList
    #print "Expected Trails"
    #print summ/300


nvalues= []
runtimes = []
runtimes1 = []
runtimes2 = []
runtimes3 = []
runtimes4 = []
#color = {300: 'blue', 1000: 'green', 5000: 'red', 10000: 'black'}
def runtimer():
    for n in range(300,20000,4000):
        nvalues.append(n)
        #stmt = 'starter(' + str(n)+','+str(300) + ')'
        #stmt1 = 'starter(' + str(n)+','+str(800) + ')'
        stmt2 = 'starter(' + str(n)+','+str(1000) + ')'
        stmt3 = 'starter(' + str(n)+','+str(3000) + ')'
        stmt4= 'starter(' + str(n)+','+str(5000) + ')'
        print(nvalues)
        #runtimes.append(timeit.timeit(stmt, setup="from __main__ import starter", number = 1))
        #runtimes1.append(timeit.timeit(stmt1, setup="from __main__ import starter", number = 1))
        runtimes2.append(timeit.timeit(stmt2, setup="from __main__ import starter", number = 1))
        print runtimes2
        runtimes3.append(timeit.timeit(stmt3, setup="from __main__ import starter", number = 1))
        runtimes4.append(timeit.timeit(stmt4, setup="from __main__ import starter", number = 1))

    fig = plt.figure()
    #plt.plot(nvalues, runtimes, c='blue', label='m = 300')
    #plt.plot(nvalues, runtimes1, c='green', label='m = 800')
    plt.plot(nvalues, runtimes2, c='red', label='m = 1000')
    plt.plot(nvalues, runtimes3, c='blue', label='m = 3000')
    plt.plot(nvalues, runtimes4, c='green', label='m = 5000')
    plt.ylabel('Runtimes')
    plt.xlabel('Coupon Collector Domain Size')
    plt.title('Plot of Coupon Collector runtimes')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.grid(True)
    fig.savefig('ccFinal.png')
runtimer()
```

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: `num not in numDict.keys()` will be really inefficient on python2.x  (It creates a new list and then does an O(n) lookup in the list).  Use `num not in numDict` instead :-) which does an O(1) lookup.

Comment: You've tagged this with `python-3.x` but you have Python 2 print statements and Python 2 methods like `has_key`, so you must be using Python 2..

Comment: I am using python 3, I have done the above suggestions. Any other improvements?

Comment: @user3388770: let me try this again.  Your line `print trailList` is *invalid* in Python 3.  Either you're not running Python 3 or you're not running that code.

Comment: I modified it but it was running.